# How can I create a SoapVar containing CDATA with XML?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have to call a SOAP web service using a SoapClient object. One of the parameters has to contain some XML included in a CDATA section, like this:

```
<ns2:productInformation><![CDATA[<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>]]></ns2:productInformation>
```

Note the node namespace, it's the source of my pain...

If I create a string `SoapVar`, the XML is encoded...

```
new SoapVar('<![CDATA[<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>]]>', XSD_STRING, null, null, 'productInformation', self::MY_NAMESPACE)

<ns2:productInformation xsi:type="xsd:string">&lt;![CDATA[&lt;foo&t;&lt;bar&gt;baz&lt;/bar&gt;&lt;/foo&gt;]]&gt;</ns2:productInformation>
```

So I can't do this way. The only alternative I've found is to use the `XSD_ANYXML` encoding, like this:

```
new SoapVar('<ns2:productInformation><![CDATA[<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo>]]></ns2:productInformation>', XSD_ANYXML)
```

It works, but it's bad... Look at the hard coded namespace shortcut ("ns2").

So do you have an idea to create a CDATA section containing XML?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same requirement (maldesigned vendor web service that requires embedding of part of the request as XML encoded in a string, and which blows up if you give it an entity-encoded string instead of CDATA).

To the best of my ability to determine, your `SoapVar` workaround is as good as it gets.  Sorry. I'm pretty unhappy about having to hardcode a namespace reference myself.